# Windows .bat script to recursively archive (with 7zip) files in subfolders

Tags: windows, command-line, archiving, 7-zip

I'm struggling to achieve the following

```
    DIR1
    FileA
    FileB
    SUBDIR2
    --->FileC
    --->FileD
    --->SUBDIR3
    ------>FileE
    ------>FileF

    etc
```

and end up with :

```
    DIR1
    DIR1.7z
    SUBDIR2
    --->SUBDIR2.7z
    --->SUBDIR3
    ------>SUBDIR3.7z

    and at each level there would be multiple subdirectories and files
```

I have a working batch file that will recursively 7zip each file in to a separate archive but for another purpose (hiding sub directory names automatically) I am trying to work out how to at each subdirecty level put the files in to an archive for each subdirectory

any help greatfully received

here is my working script to archive separate files to separate archives at a file level in case it helps others

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SET /A COUNT=0
FOR /D /r %%F in ("") DO (
pushd %CD%
cd %%F
FOR %%X in (.*) DO (
SET /A COUNT+=1
REM ECHO !COUNT!
REM ENCRYPT SEQUENTIALLY RENAME FILE
"C:\Program Files\7-zip\7z.exe" a -t7z -r -mx3 -pdog -mhe=on %date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%-!COUNT!.7z "%%X"
REM DELETE SOURCE FILE
DEL /F /S /Q /A "%%X"
)
popd
)
```

thx in advance 
ian

Comment: I'm not trying to be the party pooper but I think this would be magnitudes easier with a linux shell either on Linux or via CYGWIN or else you can use power-shell

Comment: @arielnmz why? so what if it is bat or bash. bash has more expert users but bat has enough

Comment: a generic way that is cheating a bit is to make a file listing all files with paths, then run regexes on it till it lists each individual 7z command then rename it as bat and run it.

Comment: the solution (i dont really know 7zip or cmd scripting much) is probably going to be replacing my FOR %%X in (.*) DO ( ...   just with an alternative 7zip command line that zips up all the files in that directory and leaves the subfolders if there are any 7zip experts out there (fingers x)